# Conjugate prior for a binomial-like distribution

Tags: probability, bayesian, predictive-models, conjugate-prior

Every week, my $m-1$ friends and I enter a pub quiz which has $n$ points available. In any given week only some of us are there. Record the presence/absence of member $i$ in week $t$ in the matrix $x_{ti}$.

I'd like to build a predictive model for the number of points we score in any given week, depending on who's there. A simple model is to assume that each question is equally hard, and that player $i$ has probability $p_i$ of knowing any question. Then the probability that we get a given question correct is

$$q({\bf x},{\bf p}) = 1 - \prod_{i=1}^m(1-p_i)^{x_i}$$

Therefore, the probability that we score $k$ points is

$$P({\rm Score} = k|{\bf x},{\bf p}) = {n\choose k}q^k(1-q)^{n-k}$$

and the log-likelihood for a given ${\bf p}$ and ${\bf x}$ is

$$L = \log {n\choose k} + k\log q + (n-k)\log(1-q)$$

I can write a numerical routine which maximises this, to find the maximum-likelihood estimator for $\bf p$. However, the resulting estimate badly overfits the data (as can be detected by cross validation).

A good solution seems to be to introduce a penalty (regularization) term into $L$, which penalizes large or small probabilities. As I understand it, this is equivalent to having a prior on $\bf p$. However, I don't know what the form of this prior should be. Two simple choices for the penalty term are:

$$\| {\bf p} - 1/2\|^2$$

and

$$-\sum_i\log \left( \frac{p_i}{1-p_i}\right)$$

but these are very ad-hoc. I'd be interested to know what an appropriate conjugate prior is (assuming one even exists). Any hints?

Answer (score 5):

There's no conjugate prior for this likelihood. Likelihoods that admit conjugate distributions correspond to data distributions that are members of some [exponential family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family). Having a non-linear function of the parameters in the log-likelihood makes it impossible for the data distribution to belong to an exponential family.

Even though there's no conjugate prior, one possibility for a reasonable log-prior is

$L_0({\bf p} ; {\bf j}, {\bf N} ) = \sum_i [j_i \log(p_i) + (N_i - j_i) \log (1 - p_i)]$

You can think of this log-prior as equivalent to a log-likelihood for a data set in which each person did a set of questions alone and correctly answered $j_i$ out of $N_i$. This interpretation allows you to set the prior parameters ${\bf j}$ and ${\bf N}$ in a reasonably intuitive way. I'd be somewhat surprised if even small values of $N_i$ (e.g., 2 to 4) did not provide good regularization. Note that $j_i$ and $N_i$ need not be integers.

It seems to me that you're thinking of using the plug-in predictive distribution. May I suggest you go full Bayes and use the [posterior predictive distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_predictive_distribution) instead? It would require [MCMC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain_Monte_Carlo), which may be more trouble than you're willing to go to. (If you're using Matlab I can recommend an MCMC routine that would shorten your coding time considerably.)

Comment: I think your affirmation "Likelihoods that admit conjugate distributions correspond to data distributions that are members of some exponential family" is not entirely correct. This family has a natural conjugate prior but the definition of conjugate prior is not limited to the exponential family, though it is difficult/impractical for most distributions out of this family. (+1) for the rest of the answer.

Comment: @Procrastinator, can you give me some examples? I don't doubt you -- I just want to increase my knowledge.

Comment: I do not remember any reference of this at the moment but you can find a discussion on this [here](http://www.johndcook.com/CompendiumOfConjugatePriors.pdf) or in the reference of the creators of the concept [here](http://www.amazon.com/Applied-Statistical-Decision-Theory-Howard/dp/047138349X).